# Добавление нескольких условий при фильтрации столбца pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Неободимо преобразовать столбец "Итоговая цена" по условиям:

1. Если df['Склад'] = Nan, то в df['Итоговая цена'] значение остается неизменным.
2. Если в df['Склад'] = 1 и df['Цена склада'] = Nan, то в df['Итоговая цена'] ставим 1
3. Если в df['Склад'] = 1 и df['Цена склада'] = len() > 0 (если поле не пустое), то в df['Итоговая цена'] ставим значение из df['Цена склада']
4. Если в df['Склад'] = 2 и df['Итоговая цена'] != 0, то df['Итоговая цена'] = 1, Ну а если в df['Склад'] = 2 и df['Итоговая цена'] = 0, то в df['Итоговая цена'] ничего не меняем. Пусть ноль и остается.

В остальных случаях, поле df['Итоговая цена'] не меняется.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Склад': [np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2, 2, 2, np.nan, 1, 1, np.nan],
           'Цена склада': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 100000, 30000, np.nan],
           'Итоговая цена': [0, 80600, np.nan, 55000, 13500, np.nan, 99200, np.nan, 135000, 120400]})
df['Итоговая цена'] = df['Итоговая цена'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Вот какой результат необходим:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас у меня такой код:

```
df['Итоговая цена'] = np.where((df['Склад'] == 1) & (df['Цена склада'] == np.nan), 1, df['Итоговая цена']).astype(int)
df['Итоговая цена'] = np.where((df['Склад'] == 1) & (df['Цена склада'] != np.nan), df['Цена склада'], df['Итоговая цена']).astype(int)
df['Итоговая цена'] = np.where((df['Склад'] == 2) & (df['Итоговая цена'] != 0), 1, df['Итоговая цена']).astype(int)
```

Но почему то первый код выполняется не корректно. Я поставил условие если склад = 1 и Итоговая цена = пустому значению, но почему то он игнорирует это пустое значение и применяет ко всем полям.

Comment: А какой результат получается у вас сейчас?

Comment: К сожалению, никакого. Я не знаю как это реализовать правильно.

Comment: Посмотрите функции loc и where, может придёт что-то в голову.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Два замечания:

- на `NA` надо проверять через метод `isna`, простые сравнения с `NA` не работают, это же не число ("Not a Number")
- если альтернативой у вас является "оставить как есть", то лучше использовать не `np.where`, а присваивать через `.loc` по маске, так вы не будете переписывать в каждой строчке весь датасет какими-то значениями, а измените только строки, подходящие по условию

Примерно так должно получиться:

```
df.loc[(df['Склад'] == 1) & (df['Цена склада'].isna()), 'Итоговая цена'] = 1
df.loc[(df['Склад'] == 1) & (~df['Цена склада'].isna()), 'Итоговая цена'] = df['Цена склада']
df.loc[(df['Склад'] == 2) & (df['Итоговая цена'] != 0), 'Итоговая цена'] = 1
```

Comment: Спасибо. Да, все так работает.

Comment: Кстати, можно объединить первое и третье условие в одно через | и ещё скобки, но будет выглядеть громоздко

Comment: Да, спасибо. Уже разобрался. Нет цели экономить место. Я начинающий, поэтому пусть лучше код будет читаем для меня.